# How to filter list by multiple criterias without reloading page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter, asp.net-ajax

I have product list and I should to filter products by multiple criterias. In one page I have multiple criterias (name, price, create date etc.) in differenet elements:  textbox, Dropdownlist etc. 
I want to search products without reload page. When I change any criteria, product list updates automatically, without reloading page. Like this: [Filter users.](http://www.freelancer.com/d/skills/all/)

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
    <section id="sidebar left">
       <div class="form_info">
           <label>Category</label>
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-", new { id = "ProductCategory" })
       </div>

       <div class="form_info">
            <label>Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new{ id = "ProductName"})
       </div>
    ...//other properties
    </section>

<section id="content" >
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<a class="productStyle" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { id=item.Id})">@item.Name</a>
}
</section>
```

I have `FilterProductByCriteria(int CategoryId, int Name, double priceFrom, double PriceTo..etc)` action in controller.

I can do this: in `onchange()` event of every element to send all criteria values to controller and call back result data - filtered product list, but I cannot use returned data in `@foreach (var item in Model)`. Help me in it or advice better ways, please. (Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do this: in onchange() event of every element to send all
>   criteria values to controller and call back result data - filtered
>   product list, but I cannot use returned data in `@foreach (var item in
>   Model)`

Why not? Sure you can. As an alternative you could place the filter criteria inputs inside an HTML form and provide a submit button that will send the values to the controller and this controller will return the same view with filtered products model. And then you could optimize this by introducing AJAX. You would place the `<section id="content">` contents into a partial view which will contain the filtered results. And then you could use an `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of a regular `Html.BeginForm` to send the filter criteria to the controller action. In turn this controller action will perform the filtering and pass the filtered product list to the same partial view (`return PartialView()`) which will then be used to refresh only results section of your DOM.

For example:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content" }))
{
    <section id="sidebar left">
        <div class="form_info">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                model => model.CategoryId, 
                ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                "-", 
                new { id = "ProductCategory" }
            )
        </div>

        <div class="form_info">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "ProductName"})
        </div>
        ...//other properties
    </section>

    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
}

<section id="content">
    @Html.Partial("_Products", Model)
</section>
```

and then your controller action might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchCriteriaViewModel model)
{
    IEnumerable<Product> filteredProducts = ... you know what to do here
    return PartialView("_Products", filteredProducts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this works, but filter returns only partial view. in result only partial view shown, not my search page. How can I see updates in  pages without reloading?

Comment: Did you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page?

Comment: Do you have any advice about this: when change any criteria element, to make work submit button?

Comment: Using javascript you could subscribe to the `change` event of the input fields you are interested in and then manually trigger the submission of the AJAX form.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for searching inside ASP.Net GridView without refresh the page.

[ASP.NET GridView Searching without refresh whole Page]

http://www.ashishblog.com/search-sort-in-gridview-using-c-net-ajax-and-jquery/

Here is my aspx page having search text box and gridview inside AJAX update panel.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
      Search: <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"  />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>

            <div class="GridviewDiv">


                 <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                    AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="dsGridview" Width="540px" PageSize="10" CssClass="yui">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id" ItemStyle-Width="40px"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstname" Text='<%# HighlightText(Eval("FirstName").ToString()) %>' runat="server"
                                    CssClass="TextField" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLastname" Text='<%# HighlightText(Eval("LastName").ToString()) %>' runat="server"
                                    CssClass="TextField" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department"
                            ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location"
                            ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtSearch" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

--> Here is my code behind file add method in page load event.

```
   string SearchString = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
txtSearch.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "setTimeout('__doPostBack(\\'" + txtSearch.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "\\',\\'\\')', 0);");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SearchString = txtSearch.Text;
    }
    public string HighlightText(string InputTxt)
    {
        string Search_Str = txtSearch.Text.ToString();
        // Setup the regular expression and add the Or operator.
        Regex RegExp = new Regex(Search_Str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Highlight keywords by calling the 
        //delegate each time a keyword is found.
        return RegExp.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));
        // Set the RegExp to null.
        RegExp = null;
    }
    public string ReplaceKeyWords(Match m)
    {
        return "<span class=highlight>" + m.Value + "</span>";
    }
```